# If $p$ prime, $a∈\mathbb{Z}$ , $n∈\mathbb{N}$, $g∈\mathbb{Z} [x]$, deg $g < n$, $p \nmid g(a)$ then $(x − a)^n + p · g(x)$ irred. $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Context is a course covering field theory (ch. 13) and Galois theory (ch. 14) of Abstract Algebra by Dummit & Foote. I've showed (a), that $h(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. A similar solution can be found in [A curious condition for f being irreducible in Q[x]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370590/a-curious-condition-for-f-being-irreducible-in-mathbbqx)

(a) Let $p$ be a prime number. For a polynomial $F ∈ \mathbb{Z} [x]$ we denote by
$\bar{F}$ the reduction of $F$ modulo $p$. Recall that this means that $\bar{F}$ is the polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ that arises by reducing the coeﬃcients of $F$ modulo $p$. The reduction modulo
$p$ gives a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} [x] → \mathbb{F}_
p [x]$.

Now suppose that $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$ and $f, g ∈ \mathbb{Z} [x]$ are such that: $f$ is monic with $\bar{f}$ irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p [x]$,
$\bar{f}$ and $\bar{g}$ are relatively prime in $\mathbb{F}_
p [x]$ (meaning that $\bar{f}$ and $\bar{g}$ have no common factor of degree $> 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p [x]$), and for the polynomial $h(x) :=
f(x)^n + p · g(x)$ we have deg $g$ $<$ deg $h$.

Show that then $h(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q} [x]$. (Hint: Recall that, by Gauss’ lemma, if $h(x)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Q} [x]$ then it is also reducible in $\mathbb{Z} [x]$.)

(b) Use part (a) to show the following. If $p$ is a prime number, $a ∈ \mathbb{Z}$ , $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$ , and $g ∈ \mathbb{Z} [x]$ has deg $g < n$, and is such that $p \nmid g(a)$ then the polynomial
$(x − a)^n + p · g(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q} [x]$.

(c)  Let $p$ be a prime number. Use part (b) to give a proof – diﬀerent from the one you can ﬁnd in the book (page 554) – that the polynomial
$Φ_p (x) := x^{p−1}+ . . . + x + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q} [x]$. (Hint: Note that $Φ_p (x) =\frac{x^p−1}{x−1}$. Use the rule $(a+b)^p = a^p +b^p$
(“Freshman’s dream”) that holds in any ring of characteristic $p$; in particular, the
rule holds in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_p [x]$.)

So I'm at (b) and I suppose since $(x-a)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $\overline{(x-a)}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, so what is left to show is $\overline{(x-a)}$ and $\overline{g}$ are relatively prime before you can use the result of (a). I suppose it has something to do with $p \nmid g(a)$ but I don't know.
No idea how to get started with (c).

Comment: What can a possible factor of a linear polynomial be?

Comment: It can be itself?

Comment: The only non-trivial divisor of (x-a) is (x-a)? So g(x) has to be equal to (x-a) to divide (x-a). But then g(a)=(a-a)=0 which contradicts p not being a divisor of g(a)?

Comment: We want to look at common divisors of the two

Comment: Thanks, think I got it now. Now only to do the part (c).

Comment: Think about the potential values of $n$. Can you give an alternate expression for $\phi$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ using the hint? (Assumptions for $p$?) Given the above, can you find $a$ and $g$?

Comment: $\overline{Φ_p(x)}=\overline{\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}}=\frac{\overline{x^p-1}}{\overline{x-1}}=\frac{\overline{x^p-1^p}}{\overline{x-1}}=\frac{\overline{x-1}^p}{\overline{x-1}}=\overline{x-1}^{p-1}$.

Not sure about the second equality but I used the hint for the fourth. 

Then there exists (I think?) $q(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $p\nmid q(1)$, $deg(q)<p-1$ and $Φ_p(x)=\overline{x-1}^{p-1}+p\cdot q(x)$ and we use the result of (b) to complete the proof.

Comment: Right, can you think of a trivial $q$? The second equality does indeed make sense - think of it instead as $\overline{\phi_p(x)(x-1)}=\overline{x^p-1}$

Comment: The last equation was to be without the bar so $Φ_p(x)=(x-1)^{p-1}+p\cdot q(x)$.
I have been trying to find $q$ by plugging some primes into $Φ_p(x)$ and $(x-1)^{p-1}$ but no luck.

Comment: Would a polynomial of degree 0 work?

Comment: No, I think it would have to be of degree p-2 with the constant being 0.

Comment: Why is that the case?

Comment: $(x-1)^{p-1}$ is monic and the constant term is 1, just like $Φ_p(x)$ for a p prime. (Edit: except for p=2).

Comment: Perhaps you don't need to find a particular $q$. Proving that $p\nmid q(1)$, and that $q\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ suffices. Can you do this? (My bad!)

Comment: I don't think I can do this without $q\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Comment: Well we know that $pq(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, so...

Comment: To prove the latter, consider what it means for $\phi_p\equiv(x-1)^{p-1}$

Answer (score 1):

(b)  $\overline{g(a)} = \overline{g}(\overline{a})$. As $p \nmid g(a)$ we have $0 \neq \overline{g}(\overline{a}) \in \mathbb{F}_p$ , i.e. $\overline{a}$ is
not a root of $\overline{g}$. This shows that $x − \overline{a}$ and $\overline{g}$ are relatively prime in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. As the
reduction modulo $p$ of $x − a$ is $x − \overline{a}$, part (a) now applies.

(c) The polynomials $x^p − 1$ and $(x − 1)^p$ are equal
in $\mathbb{F}_p [x]$. As a consequence,
the reductions modulo $p$ of the polynomials
$Φ_p(x)=\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}$ and $\frac{(x-1)^p}{x-1}=(x-1)^{p-1}$ are the same. This means $Φ_p(x)=(x-1)^{p-1}+p\cdot g(x)$ for some $g \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. 
Since $Φ_p(x)$ and $(x − 1)^{p−1}$ are both monic,
we must have deg $g$ $<$ deg $Φ_p = p − 1$. Since $Φ_p (1) = p$ we see $g(1) = 1$ and
hence part (b) applies with $a = 1$.